# What is the entry point/command required to run an etcd container in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, etcd

With all of the entry points and commands I've tried so far, I'm getting this error "no such file or directory."
I need to:
1) Set an env variable for HostIP using a special curl request to AWS
2) Run the etcd container, giving it arguments that use $HostIP

It seems that it takes a string array, but I'm not sure how it works. I'm thinking the commands are:

```
/bin/sh -c "export export HostIP=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)"
```

and

```
etcd -advertise-client-urls http://${HostIP}:2379,http://${HostIP}:4001
 -other-similar-args...
```

but I need to change them to be comma separated.

1) How do I escape the commas/quotes?
2) Do I need to use a comma and start a new string for every space?
3) Does anyone have a working example???

Update: I made a custom container with an entrypoint.sh which contains this:

```
 #!/bin/sh export HOST=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname) export HostIP=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

 /usr/local/bin/etcd  -name etcd0 \  -advertise-client-urls
 http://${HostIP}:2379,http://${HostIP}:4001 \  -listen-client-urls
 http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \ 
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${HostIP}:2380 \  -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \  -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \  -initial-cluster etcd0=http://${HostIP}:2380 \ 
 -initial-cluster-state new
```

Now the issue is that the container starts up but uses localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 or the IP we fetch with curl from AWS. It seems to suffer some kind of error and falls back to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

When running tasks from the ECS dashboard command line arguments need to be separated by commas, but keep in mind that the whole string passed to `sh -c` is a single argument interpreted by the sub-shell.

In other words your task definition should looks as follows:

```
/bin/sh,-c,export HostIP=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4) && etcd ...
```

However, if you have control over the image then you could consider writing a custom ENTRYPOINT script that encapsulates all of that.

Comment: Thank you - I made my own image and put everything in an entrypoint.sh, then left ECS entrypoint/command empty. Now the problem is that there's something wrong in the image - the HostIP address seems to to fall back to a default of 127.0.0.1 instead of the one I pass it. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
export HOST=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)
export HostIP=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

/usr/local/bin/etcd
 -name etcd0 \
 -advertise-client-urls http://${HostIP}:2379,http://${HostIP}:4001 \
 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${HostIP}:2380 \
 -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 -initial-cluster etcd0=http://${HostIP}:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-state new

Comment: Anything interesting in task logs? You could add `echo $HostIP $HOST` for debugging purposes and check the value in logs. If this works fine then it might be something etcd-specific.